# Archivos residuales en MYSQL - PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Hace un tiempo limpié bastante una BD, quitándole alrededor de 10GB de información innecesaria.
Pesaba sobre 47GB y lo deje en 31GB aprox.

Ahora, este cambio de 10GB+ no se vee reflejado en CPANEL. Lo que me preocupa de si existe archivo residual que no pueda ver.

PHPMYADMIN 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CPANEL 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se supone que cpanel te muestra el total de todas las bases de datos que tenga esa cuenta. ¿No tienes más bases de datos en la cuenta?

Comment: Hay más, pero no pasan de sumar 100mb juntas.

Comment: Ni idea entonces.  Se que a veces el sistema de archivos puede tener la culpa si los clusteres son relativamente grandes y no estan ocupados completamente, provocando discrepancias entre el tamaño real de un archivo y el tamaño real ocupado en clústeres. pero 16GB me parece demasiado.

Comment: Aqui comentan algo al respecto relativo a tu caso: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4408316841751-Difference-in-database-size-in-cPanel-and-phpMyAdmin

Comment: El tamaño **real** de **esa** BD se puede saber ejecutando esta consulta: `SELECT table_schema "AQUINOMBREREALDELABD",
        ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY table_schema;`  [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733523/5587982). Si te muestra el tamaño correcto entonces no es un problema de **esa base de datos**, podría serlo de cPanel o de otra cosa. Por otra parte, dinos a qué corresponde la segunda imagen que muestras en tu pregunta ¿?